# Properties of $\lim \sup$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

> Suppose {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} are bounded sequences and that lim $b_n =b$. Prove
>   that $$\lim \sup (a_n + b_n) = \lim \sup a_n + b. $$

Here is what I  tried:

---

Consider $$\sup (a_k) + b$$
Since $b$ is a fixed number, and $\sup (a_k) = \sup \{ a_n : n\geq k \} $, then it follows that
$$\sup (a_k) + b  = \sup (a_k + b)$$
**(is this correct?)**

Then since $b_k \rightarrow b $, for $k \geq N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough,  $ b_k - \epsilon \leq b \leq b_k + \epsilon$. So
 $$ \sup (a_k + b_k - \epsilon) \leq   \sup (a_k + b) \leq \sup (a_k + b_k + \epsilon)$$

Since this holds for all $k \geq N$, we can take the limit as $k$ approaches $\infty$,
 $$\lim \sup (a_k + b_k - \epsilon) \leq \lim  \sup (a_k + b) \leq \lim \sup (a_k + b_k + \epsilon)$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that 
$$\lim \sup (a_n + b_n) = \lim \sup a_n + b. $$

Comment: You need to work on your writing. I think you've got the right direction but it's not clear.

Comment: I would go a slightly different route. Remember that

$$\inf x_n \leqslant \liminf x_n \leqslant \limsup x_n \leqslant \sup x_n \tag{1}$$

and that $\lim x_n$ exists if and only if $\liminf x_n = \limsup x_n$.

Combine this with the following very useful inequalities for the $\limsup$ of bounded sequences (more generally, for when there are no indeterminates):

$$\limsup a_n + \liminf b_n \leqslant \limsup (a_n + b_n) \leqslant \limsup a_n + \limsup b_n \tag{2}$$

If you have not proven the inequalities $(2)$, I think it would be a good exercise.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  I like your approach better, but is it correct that $\sup(a_k) + b = \sup(a_k + b)$ (in my originial post)?

Comment: Yes it is! This can be easily shown directly from the definitions if not already proven or discussed in class/textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it from scratch, go back to the definition of $\limsup$. Set $g_k=\sup_{n\ge k}\{a_n\}$ and $h_k=\sup_{n\ge k}\{b_n\}.$ Then, for all $n\ge k,$

$a_n+b_n\le g_k+h_k$ so $\sup_{n\ge k}(a_n+b_n)\le g_k+h_k=\sup_{n\ge k}\{a_n\}+\sup_{n\ge k}\{b_n\}.$ That is,

$\tag1 \sup_{n\ge k}(a_n+b_n)\le  \sup_{n\ge k}\{a_n\}+\sup_{n\ge k}\{b_n\}.$

So, in our case

$\tag2 \underset{k\to \infty}\lim\sup_{n\ge k}(a_n+b_n)\le  \underset{k\to \infty}\lim\sup_{n\ge k}\{a_n\}+\underset{k\to \infty}\lim\sup_{n\ge k}\{b_n\}=\underset{k\to \infty}\lim\sup_{n\ge k}\{a_n\}+b,$

which is of course

$\tag3 \limsup (a_n + b_n)\le \limsup a_n+b$

For the reverse inequality, we use a trick: $a_n = (a_n + b_n) + (-b_n)$ and now $(3)$ gives

$\tag4 \limsup a_n\le \limsup (a_n + b_n)-b\Rightarrow \limsup a_n+b\le \limsup (a_n + b_n).$